# splitting comma separated list into a temp table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, regexp-substr

I want to convert the following IN query into inner join query :

```
select country, name, rank from table person_details 
   where country in ('india','USA','australia') 
   and   name in ('tom', 'jill', 'jack') 
   and   rank in ('first', 'third', 'fifith');
```

I have two questions:

1. this table is big so will changing this IN query into inner join will speed up things.
2. What will be best way to split this comma separated list to a column in some temp table. I have see many regex examples but they seem too complex and big.

I am using Oracle 11g DB.

Table snapshot :

```
Id   name   country   rank
 1    tom    india     first
 2    jill   USA      second
 3    jack   aus       first
```

Comment: i dont think here `self join` will work faster than `IN` , create index on `country` and `rank` which will help in speed up. and regarding comma separated list...I will say 'Have a table structure atleast in `1NF`'. If your table not in `1NF` you may face serious performance issues.

Comment: See the examples here https://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/category/oracle-delimited-string-manipulation/

Comment: @LalitKumarB Good One..!!!

Comment: @NagendraNigade Thanks. I see this FAQ that I tried to cover all possible scenarios in my article.

Comment: @LalitKumarB i gues i was not clear with my question. table snapshot i have attached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> select country, name, rank from table person_details

The query is syntactically incorrect. you don't need the keyword TABLE. Just do:

`select country, name, rank from person_details`

Strictly speaking, your table is not **normalized**. You should not store multiple values in a single column. Sooner or later you will see the performance issues. It is never too late to re-design your tables and store the values in separate columns.

Having said that, there are many ways to split comma delimited string into rows. here is one simple way using **REGEXP_SUBSTR** and **INSTR** in **CONNECT BY** clause:

```
SQL> WITH DATA AS(
  2  select q'['india','USA','australia']' countries,
  3  q'['tom', 'jill', 'jack']' names,
  4  q'['first', 'third', 'fifth']' ranks
  5  from dual
  6  )
  7  SELECT regexp_substr(translate(countries,'''',' '), '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) countries,
  8  trim(regexp_substr(translate(names,'''',' '), '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)) names,
  9  trim(regexp_substr(translate(ranks,'''',' '), '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)) ranks
 10  FROM DATA
 11  CONNECT BY instr(countries, ',', 1, LEVEL - 1) > 0
 12  /

COUNTRIES                 NAMES                 RANKS
------------------------- --------------------- -------------------------
 india                    tom                   first
 USA                      jill                  third
 australia                jack                  fifth

SQL>
```

I have demonstrated other ways in my article [ORACLE DELIMITED STRING MANIPULATION](https://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/category/oracle-delimited-string-manipulation/).

Comment: hi lalit, columns do not have multiple values. CSV are the filter selection criteria by a user. if this is what you meant.

Comment: yeah thanks it does. but do we have to do all this operation for converting CSV to a temp table column. If yes then please could you just give a brief of as how this query is working. I could not figure this out. MSSQL had simpler ways of doing this.

Comment: It is a simple method. All i am doing is, using `regexp_substr` extracting each substring between the commas, and then the connect by clause will convert it into rows. The LEVEL indicates the row increment. There are 3 values, so level will be 3 in this case. Please mark it answered so that it helps others to find this as a correct solution.

Comment: one one thing more lalit. this CSV to table will give me a temp table and now i want to use this result to do inner join with another table how can i do this. i am pasting queries i have tried.

Comment: one one thing more lalit. this CSV to table will give me a temp table and now i want to use this result to do inner join with another table how can i do this. i am pasting queries i have tried.


select distinct account_id , account from accounts inner join
(WITH DATA AS(
select q'['India','USA']' countries from dual) 
SELECT regexp_substr(translate(countries,'''',' '), '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL) countries FROM DATA
CONNECT BY instr(countries, ',', 1, LEVEL - 1) > 0 ) Temp on accounts.BILLING_COUNTRY = Temp.countries;

Comment: That now how you join with the WITH clause. You need to simply consider the WITH as a table. So, do it as `WITH DATA AS(...) SELECT column_list FROM DATA INNER JOIN ACCOUNTS...`